# Changing the Main Camera background

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to change the background of my `Main Camera` on Unity 4.6.9f1, but it doesn't seem to open the colour picker for me to be able to change it. Here's what I tried:

[image]

I tried to click all over on the `Background` option, and it didn't seem to open the colour picker. However, clicking on the pen like thing selects some random colour. Any help would be highly appreciated. :)

Comment: Either it opens and is behind something or it doesn't open and it's a bug.

Comment: Hi Hassan, the "random" selection from the picker icon is correct, because it "scans" for the colors of the visible elements in the window. Regarding the click issue on the colored area, that's strange, but there's a possibility: do you use an external monitor, sometimes? My tought (in that case) is that the color picker window could be placed at a "coordinate" that goes beyond the single screen's space. This could happens when you had an external monitor.

Comment: @Andrea Yes, I do use an external monitor. One doesn't suffice.

Comment: @user3071284 Unfortunately, I believe it is a final release.

Comment: Unity's final releases always have bugs. I think it is likely, however, that @Andrea is right.

Answer (score 0):

Set your Clear Flags from Skybox to Solid Color.  You can change the background in Unity -> Preferences -> Colors - this changes the default - or use the eye dropper ("pen like thing") by clicking it once then clicking anywhere on your screen that has the color you'd like to use (it selects the color of the pixel you click on - the eye dropper tool is very common in image editing software like Photoshop).

Comment: That think doesn't open for me. Tried that.

Comment: And, I'm sorry that it changes the background of the Scene, not the Main Camera.

Comment: There's nothing to open.  It's not a dialog, it just changes the cursor, then you just click a color somewhere that you want to use.  For a color picker, you need to change the default.  But maybe I don't understand what you want?  The camera background color defines the background of the scene in lieu of any other image or geometry, and two cameras can look at the same scene with different background colors.  It's only static to the camera, not actually to the scene.  If you want a static background for the scene, use an image, even a 1px x 1px black pixel that you scale to be the size needed

Comment: I want a color-picker. The tutorial I follow has one

Comment: But different versions of Unity can have grossly different usability for the smaller aspects of things.  That said, I still stand by the statement that the background per camera is independent and not a true scene background.  If you need a true scene background for a 2D app in Unity, you really need to actually just set a background image.

Comment: I know, but I'm new to Unity, and therefore, my course requires coloured backgrounds for now, and on that edition, the color picker, etc opens perfectly.